# URLs redirecting to index.php when no protocol

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal

Hoping someone with more htaccess experience can help us with this. We have Drupal 7 site that we have just moved from a dev to the live host (different hosting companies). However, now when someone puts a url with no protocol directly into the address bar (for example: examplesite.com/members), the page redirects to examplesite.com/index.php. I have been muddling around trying to fix this in the htaccess file, but have not been able to find the proper syntax for allowing urls with no protocol, while also forcing https://.

Our code:

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

We have tried moving the RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] line to underneath all rules, or commenting it out. This fixed the initial problem,  but breaks the drupal admin functionality on the backend (can't see the admin menu, can't save anything, etc)

Any insight would be helpful, let me know if more info is needed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `/$1` in your RewriteRule instead of `%{REQUEST_URI}`? (And add the flag QSA if you also want to keep any possible query string.)

Comment: What do you mean by URL with no protocol? When you type `examplesite.com/members` in your browser, browser actually sends `http://examplesite.com/members` to web server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the entire block, conditions + rule to the bottom. Drupal routes everything through the `index.php` script and it requires the previous 3 conditions in order to do that properly. If you simply move the `RewriteRule` line, then the conditions are all gone.

```
RewriteEngine On

# this needs to come first
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# then drupal stuff comes LAST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```